# How to implement form-based authentification without SSL/TLS

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, ssl, web

I am building a small website to learn web development.

I would like to have a secure authentication system. After [some reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication), it seems like there is no way to send the credentials to my server without SSL/TLS connection.

However, an SSL connection is not suitable for me for the following reasons:

- It is complex;
- It is (most likely) not free

Is there any alternative that I could use to handle authentification ?

More specifically, I would like a way to transfer the user credentials from a form in my html page to my server without it being easy to steal using packet sniffing.

Setup: Arch Linux (ARM), Nginx, NodeJS, Mongodb

Comment: *" After some reading, it seems like there is no way to send the credentials to my server without SSL/TLS connection"* That's correct.

Comment: It _is_ the only way, and it can be free. Check out [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)

Comment: For development purposes. What are self signed certificates.

Comment: You need to provide more info like the hosting platform you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a free alternative called letsencrypt, which generates free tls certificates, have a look:

https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: This should be accepted!

Comment: @LucaKiebel no it's not OP's requirements probably extended further then just needing a free certificate. He probably doesn't know how to set everything up. Running a http webserver is simple for most but if you're​ not familiar with https then there's a learning curve and even lets encrypt is not the most noob friendly thing out there.